# Change Global Css Code using Local Css Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

If I have a css code section `{ margin-left: 80px; }` in global css and If I need to change the code into `margin-left: 40px;` by using local css code. Is it possible to do it?

Is it possibly to change the global css code by using local javascript and local css code?

A sample is provided:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-85deej

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316099/how-exactly-css-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you read about [view encapsulation here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) for more information.

Try this:

```
::ng-deep section { margin-left: 80px; }
```

Check the [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zazp5d?file=src/app/Components/sidenav/sidenav.component.css)

Comment: `::ng-deep` is marked as deprecated and will be removed at some point, you should try to avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try `margin-left: 40px!important;` in your local css, it will override global css property.

Comment: Can you share the html part as well?